# Samsung: switching to new phone

Tags: samsung, data-transfer, samsung-galaxy-s-9, samsung-smart-switch

I recently switched phones for the first time in several years. My vague recollection from past switches was that it was fairly smooth. Here is what happened this time.

I switched from a Galaxy S9, Android 10, to a Galaxy S9+, also Android 10.

After starting the already factory-reset S9+ I entered my Google account details and followed the prompts.
Said prompts led me to use Smart Switch, which I have used several times in the past. Texts, call logs, screen background, icon placement all transferred successfully in a few minutes. The phone then finished installing all the apps and that was it.

But soon I noticed that no app settings have been transferred; this ended up cascading in a couple hours of looking for passwords, re-loading my credit cards in my pay apps, having to manually backup some apps, and even having to call the IT department at work to reset the MFA settings and register the new phone. And several minor problems with other apps.

All in all, not terrible but it was quite a task to be fully functional again with the new phone. My original plan was to switch phones again fairly soon, and now I'm dreading that moment. My question is, did I do something wrong? Is there a way to have a  smoother transition between Samsung phones?

Comment: Most security related apps are bound to the device and thus can't be migrated.

Comment: I don't doubt it, but makes little sense to me. Google/Samsung already transferred all my texts, calls, and browser passwords to the new phone with no qualms. Anyone with full access to the phone can reset any of my passwords. What's the logic of some app forcing the change manually? In any case, I'm surprised I seem to be the only one with the issue. I was ready to buy a new phone (the change was to a temporary one) and the hassle that was switching phones has made me decide not to buy one. Really surprised there is no backslash with this.

Comment: There's no reason why app settings which aren't security related should not be transferred.  Some of them may even have functionality for it in-app, in places rarely - if ever frequented, - until - alas it's too late!